# Inverse Laplace transform of a hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, laplace-transform

I managed to solve an initial value problem in the Laplace domain in terms of a special function

$
F(s) = c_2 \frac{1}{{{\left( {{s}^{1 +\beta}}-1\right) }^{\frac{1}{\beta+1}}}}+ c_1 \frac{s}{{{\left( {{s}^{1 +\beta}}-1\right) }^{\frac{1}{\beta+1}}}} \
{_{2}{F}_{1}}\left( \frac{1}{\beta+1},\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}; \frac{1}{\beta+1}+1;{{s}^{\beta+1}}\right) 
$ where $ 0 \leq \beta \leq 1$ and $ _{2}{F}_{1}$ if the hypergeometric function.

However, I am unable to find the ILT or give an approximation in the time domain in the general case.

Is there a way to invert the equation or at least to   give an approximation for short times?